# Center equations in table!

Tags: tables, equations, alignment

I can't seem to figure out how centre the equations in the column so it looks neat!!! (See my latex code below).

```
 %3 LAWS OF THERMO SECTION ----- SECTION 5

\section*{Laws of Thermodynamics}

\tcbset{enhanced, fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=red!75!black, coltitle= white,center title}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth0.5mm}{X|X|X},title=My table] 

First
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Energy can never be destroyed or \\ created.\end{tabular}
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$dU = \delta Q - \delta U $ \end{tabular}
\\\hline

Second
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Entropy of an isolated system \\ can never decrease.\end{tabular} 
&\begin{tabular}{c}$dS \geq 0$ for an isolated system\\ $\delta Q = T dS $\end{tabular}
\\\hline

Third
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} The entropy of a system approaches \\ a constant value as the temperature \\ approaches absolute zero. \\ \emph{(Entropy is zero at absolute zero)}
\end{tabular}
&\begin{tabular}{c}$S = k_B \ln \Omega$ \end{tabular}
\\\hline

Zeroth
&\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Bodies in thermal equilibrium are \\ at the same temperature
\end{tabular}                                                                                                 
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which document class your document employs and which packages are loaded by your document.

Comment: @Azhir the eqns look better left aligned -- my opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that your document employs one of the standard LaTeX document classes -- say, `article` -- and that it loads, at a minimum, the `geometry`, `tabularx`, `ragged2e`, `xcolor`, and `tcolorbox` packages -- the latter with the option `most`.

If these assumptions are essentially correct, the solution shown in the code below and the associated screenshot may be of interest to you. It employs the basic `l` column type for the first column and modified `X` column types for columns 2 and 3 -- left-aligned and centered, respectively. Given that the `X` column type allows automatic line breaking, one can dispense with the `tabular` overhead which your code incurs in almost all cells.

[image]

A suggestion: Since you employ a sans-serif text font in the table, you may want to employ a sans-serif math font as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % vertical centering
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional

\usepackage{helvet} % optional

\begin{document}
\section*{Laws of Thermodynamics}

\tcbset{enhanced, 
   fonttitle=\bfseries\large\sffamily,
   fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
   colback=red!5!white,
   colframe=red!50!black,
   colbacktitle=red!75!black, 
   coltitle= white,
   center title}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth0.5mm}{l|L|C},title=My table]

First
& Energy can never be destroyed or created.
& $dU = \delta Q - \delta U $ 
\\\hline

Second
&Entropy of an isolated system can never decrease.
&$dS \geq 0$ for an isolated system\newline $\delta Q = T dS $
\\\hline

Third
&The entropy of a system approaches a constant value as the temperature approaches absolute zero. \newline \emph{(Entropy is zero at absolute zero)}
&$S = k_B \ln \Omega$ 
\\\hline

Zeroth
&Bodies in thermal equilibrium are at the same temperature. &
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. The packages I have been using are;

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\geometry{margin = 0.5in}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{linegoal}

Once I incorporated your recommendations it looked great. (Thanks, I've just started using latex).

Comment: @azhirmahmood - Thanks for these pieces of onformation. It’s good to get confirmation that my working assumptions were “essentially correct”. :-)